# Saving the description field for hyperlink field in calendar list item

Tags: list, calendar

I wrote a web part which creates items/events in my calendar list. There is a column which holds a hyperlink field. The column name is 'Form Link'. I can write my hyperlink from my code to the list item, but I would like to know how I can write the description - so the link will show the description text instead of the actual link.

this line writes the link to the field

```
calendarListItem["Form Link"] = "/SitePages//New%20Booking.aspx?bid=" + formlink;
```

What can I add or change to also write the description to this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPFieldUrlValue is the class you are looking for.

```
SPFieldUrlValue UrlValue = new SPFieldUrlValue(formlink);
UrlValue.Url
UrlValue.Description
```

[SPFieldUrlValue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurlvalue.aspx)